# Slowing down loop in Winforms with await

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, timer

I have a loop in a Windows Forms Application that draws pixels in a certain shape, but I want to let the user see it being drawn.

The loop in question:

```
public async void Bar()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
        {
            await Task.Delay(100);

            Foo();
        }
    }
```

`Bar()` is simply called from nonstatic functions on the UI thread.

`Foo()` is supposed to draw a pixel on a bitmap, and is executed (according to the debugger) but doesn't actually draw anything. Very unusual.

If I remove the await statement, it draws perfectly.

Comment: Tried await/async, Timer, manually measuring DateTime, nothing. Thread.Sleep obviously does nothing. People keep saying "Don't block the UI thread" -- what does that even mean? That's the point, I want to delay the UI from showing.

Comment: Please post a minimal, complete reproduce of your problem. Currently, we don't have enough information to help.

Comment: See my updated answer how to do a slow animation in winforms.

Comment: The problem is not the `await` statement, but  the `async void` declaration of your method and how it is called (which you haven't provided).

Comment: Since you don't show us the real code we are limited in how we can help you. Do take note of my remarks on how to make a Bitmap show its current content. If you change it behind the scenes the UI thread will not change the display!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your code but you need to force the UI-thread to update the Bitmap you modify. To do so add this line to your `Foo`:

```
   panel1.Refresh();
```

This assumes you write to the shown bitmap property **directly** (see below!). Of course you need to change `panel1` to the control that holds the `Bitmap`; see below for the two basic situations of using an **external** `Bitmap` variable or an **'internal'** `Image` (for `PictureBox`) or `BackgroundImage` (for `Panel` or many others) property of a control!

If instead you want to work on a bitmap **variable** your `Foo` could look like this:

```
public void Foo()
{
    Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap) panel1.BackgroundImage;
    // now do your drawing stuff
    bmp.SetPixel(...);
    panel1.BackgroundImage = bmp;
    panel1.Refresh();
}
```

While this will work, the way animations usually are done is by using a `Timer`.

The key in using a `Timer` would be to break up the loop:

Move the setup up to, maybe a `Button.Click` and move the rest to a `Timer.Tick`, maybe like this:

The counter now at class level:

```
    int counter = 0;
```

The `Tick` holds the counting, check and drawing body:

```
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (counter > 1000)
        {
            timer1.Stop();
        }
        else
        {
            angle1 += angle1Modifier;
            angle2 += angle2Modifier;
            angle3 += angle3Modifier;
            DrawPixel(getPoint(angle1, angle2, angle3));
            yourCanvasControl.Refresh();
        }
    }
```

The `Click` holds the setup and starts the loop/timer:

```
    private void buttonStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        counter = 0;
        timer1.Interval = 50;
        timer1.Start();
    }
```

This works because the `Timer` is associated with the 'UI-thread' , that is the one thread that does all the display work as well as accepting all the user input.

Obviously you should not block it or else your program becomes sluggish or seems frozen, but a `Timer`, as opposed to a `Thread.Sleep` will not block the UI-thread, so it is a good choice for animations (as far as they go in Winforms).

Note: Since you are using a `SetPixel` you are modifying a `Bitmap` and  you will need to add a `Invalidate()` or `Refresh()` on the control that holds the `Bitmap` to the `Tick`  to make it show; let's look at how to do this:

If you are modifying an external `Bitmap bmp` you will need to **re-assign** it:

```
bmp.SetPixel(...);
panel1.BackgroundImage = bmp;
```

If instead your are modfying the `Image` or `BackgroundImage` directly a `Refresh` of `Invalidate` will do:

```
((Bitmap)panel1.BackgroundImage).SetPixel(...);
panel1.Invalidate();
```

Comment: Yes, that worked. I understand Timer much better now; the documentation never helps.